# Jest cannot resolve the absolute path TestPathPattern in the command line

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

but work well with relative path;

absolute path not work:  No tests found, exiting with code 1 Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0

```
jest ~/work/ze/src/web/table/RoTableElement.spec.ts
```

relative path work well

```
 jest ./table/RoTableElement.spec.ts
```

or cd ~/work/ze/src/web/table/

```
 jest RoTableElement.spec.ts
```

Comment: I find the problem ， work/ is a  symlink , jest  can not resolve it ;
https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/1477